# how get json result and display the result into bootstrap form helper

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

i have this code for get country code and use for select country in botstrap form helper plugin, like this

```
<script>
            var code;
            $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
                    code = data.country_code;
            });
           $('#country').bfhcountries({country: code, blank:false});

</script>
```

if i change the code in

> '{country: code, blank:false}'

into statis code like this

> '{country: 'ID', blank:false}'

the selected country is open, but if i use 'code' variable the selected country not open, how to solved this with statis country code.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `code` variable is declared outside the `getJSON` function but it is **initalised** in the `getJSON` **callback** function.

It should be better like this :

```
<script>
            var code;
            $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
                    code = data.country_code;
                    $('#country').bfhcountries({country: code, blank:false});
            });
</script>
```

The getJSON method is ran **in parralel** with your code.

The value of the `code` variable is equals to the `data.country_code` **BUT** `data.country_code` is only available in the `getJSON` **callback function**.

That's why, we initialised it, in the getJSON **callback**.

Comment: No, it's **declared** outside. Did you try the code above ?

Comment: @JurijJazdanov If you don't understand, you should check the **asynchronous concept** in javascript.